# Groovy get metaClass of subtype

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I try to dynamically add properties to instances of types that inherits from one common class. To make it simpler for user I want to create a helper method in super class:

```
class Super {
    void add(String propertyName, Object value) {
        this.metaClass."$propertyName" = value
    }
}

class X extends Super {
    String name
    int value
}

X a = new X(name: 'a', value: 4)
X b = new X(name: 'b', value: 5)

a.add('other', 5)
b.add('other', 4)

println a​​.other
println b.other​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This code prints:

```
4
4
```

However, if instead using the "add" method I set metaproperty directly on instance:

```
a.metaClass.other = 5
b.metaClass.other = 4

println a​​.other
println b.other​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

it prints:

```
5
4
```

I understand that there is no only one metaclass for instance but each hierarchy class has its own. Is there a way to get metaclass of subclass or I miss completely the idea?

**Update**

If I add in subclass:

```
    {
        super.setMetaClass(metaClass)
    }
```

It seems to works, however I would prefer to avoid it.

I see that subtype metaClass looks like:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@25b53784[groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@25b53784[class X]]
```

and supertype metaClass:

```
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@25b53784[class X]
```

Comment: Interestingly if I add one more super type level it works. I print metaClass for each type and the are:

groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@142d5d89[class X]

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@142d5d89[groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@142d5d89[class X]]

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@142d5d89[groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass@142d5d89[class X]]


So it looks like the highest class is different and not HandleMetaClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use parent's class `metaClass`, you need to access it using `super.metaClass` instead of `this.metaClass` like in the example shown below:

```
class Super {
    void add(String propertyName, Object value) {
        super.metaClass."$propertyName" = value
    }
}

class X extends Super {
    String name
    int value
}

X a = new X(name: 'a', value: 4)
X b = new X(name: 'b', value: 5)

a.add('other', 5)
b.add('other', 4)

println a.other
println b.other
```

Output:

```
$ groovy test.groovy
5
4
```

Alternatively, you can use trait that works fine with `this.metaClass` (trait adds the `add` method to the classes that implement trait, so `this.metaClass` works as expected in that context.)

```
trait Super {
    void add(String propertyName, Object value) {
        this.metaClass."$propertyName" = value
    }
}

class X implements Super {
    String name
    int value
}

X a = new X(name: 'a', value: 4)
X b = new X(name: 'b', value: 5)

a.add('other', 5)
b.add('other', 4)

println a.other
println b.other
```

Comment: I am testing now here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ so maybe there is smth like ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally() set ...

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Updated the answer to cover both, class and trait use cases.